# Not video output or system beeps on an old PC

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, gpu

I recently took out my old PC that was stored in an attic to use as a private game server, just for Minecraft and Tekkit. It's been stored for about 1.5 years and it worked when it was first stored.

I brought it home and it's sadly not giving any video output.

I've tried both DVI and HDMI with two different monitors that works. All the fans spin, the light on the motherboard lights up, the fans spin on the gpu, the hdd ramps up. I suspect that the GPU is faulty for some reason.

I've tried to remove the CMOS battery and taking out all but one RAM stick. I sadly don't have a left over GPU to test my theory, and I don't want to buy one if I'm not certain that's the problem.

SPECS:

- CPU: AMD Athlon II X3 450
- GPU: GeForce GTX 550 Ti 1 GB
- Motherboard: ASUS M4N68T LE V2
- RAM: Corsair XMS3 4GB (2x2GB) 1600MHz DDR III
- BOOT DRIVE: Intel 320 series 40GB OEM

Some other notes:

- I've also tried turniong it off, taking the power cable out and pressing down the power button for a minute, before turning it back on
- I've tried to unplug the GPU and put it back in. Nothing changed. I'll try to find a VGA cable
- The VGA cable did not work.
- The GPU works in my other system.
- I found a motherboard speaker and tried it on the system, but nothing happens. I have also removed both storage drives and the disc reader, but nothing
- I tried unpluggin the RAM and the speaker goes crazy

Comment: the GPU may have been bumped out of its socket slightly during transit. Try taking out the GPU and putting it back in. Also, make sure that if you have more than one video outputs, you try all of them. And lastly, try turning on, then off, then on again. Sometimes after a long time of no usage, the system just needs to have power have been run through it for a bit before it can properly start. So when you start it a second time, it boots up properly.

Comment: I need to find a VGA cable then, I'll try to reconnect the GPU as well. I also tried turning it off, unplugging the power cable and holding the power button for a minute, but to no avail

Comment: holding the power button with no cord will drain the electricity from the system. It is good to get rid of problems due to an energy imbalance, but in your case, the system was already fully drained due to 1,5 years of storage. The system needs energy at this point. So with the cable plugged in, if it doesn't boot, turn off and turn on again without unplugging the power cord.

Comment: Also, it is very likely that the BIOS was reset and that, by default, it outputs to VGA.

Comment: The VGA cable did not work

Comment: Can you try the GPU in a different system to confirm or rule out a problem with the GPU?

Comment: Could that be harmful for the other system? I only have my primary pc

Comment: No, not at all, unless you don't know what you're doing, but seeing your responses so far, I'm pretty sure you can do this without causing issues.

Comment: Great. I'll try it when I get back home

Comment: The GPU works in my other system

Comment: Okay, so you have ruled out a problem with the GPU then. Try each RAM module individually. If not it might be the motherboard or the PSU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works! I was cleaning the RAM pins and unplugged the motherboard connectors and plugged them back in and it's working!

Answer (score 0):

I have had a quick look online and I can't see if there is a speaker on the motherboard or not. Does your case have a speaker that you can plug in to test it?

If you already have a speaker plugged in, I would suggest you unplug the hard drives, take out the GPU and anything plugged in the back. Try turning it on again and you should get the beeps from the system indicating there is no RAM present. If you don't get any beeps and you can see a speaker is definitely plugged in, that would point at the CPU or motherboard being at fault.

Comment: Fan noises etc suggest that the system boots up properly, there is just no video. I highly doubt this is a faulty CPU or motherboard because that would halt the system at boot and not actually boot the system as is the case currently.

Comment: I'll try it when I get back home

Comment: I plugged in a speaker, nothing

Comment: It hasn't beeped before

Comment: Silly me, I don't have motherboard speakers

Comment: I found one in my primary system and plugged it into the other one, no beeps though